# assign a color to a specific box in seaborn.boxplot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm calling seaborn.boxplot roughly as follows:

```
   seaborn.boxplot(ax=ax1,
                    x="centrality", y="score", hue="model", data=data], 
                    palette=seaborn.color_palette("husl", len(models) +1),
                    showfliers=False, 
                    hue_order=order,
                    linewidth=1.5)
```

Is it possible to make one box stand out by giving it a specific color, while coloring all others with the given color palette?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example?

Comment: @Chiel the seaborn.boxplot docs provide a minimal example for you to play with: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- The correct method is now `.patches` instead of `artists`. However, there are different types of `patches`, so it's not as simple as selecting the 3rd patch.
- In this example, `list(ax.patches)` returns the following list:

  - The boxplot patches are the `PathPatch` objects. As such the correct `patch`, for the 3rd boxplot, is `ax.patches[4]`

```py
[<matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1fe73317910>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe72508050>,
 <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x1fe76b497d0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe6c35cc90>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe76db67d0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe6c35c610>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe715d8d90>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe6c31b0d0>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe6c2f5a90>,
 <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch at 0x1fe74df6450>]
```

```py
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips, palette="Set3")

# Select which box you want to change    
mybox = ax.patches[4]

# Change the appearance of that box
mybox.set_facecolor('red')
mybox.set_edgecolor('black')
mybox.set_linewidth(3)
```

[image]

---

The boxes made using `sns.boxplot` are really just `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch` objects. These are stored in `ax.artists` as a list.

So, we can select one box in particular by indexing `ax.artists`. Then, you can set the `facecolor`, `edgecolor` and `linewidth`, among many other properties.

For example (based on one of the examples [here](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                 data=tips, palette="Set3")

# Select which box you want to change    
mybox = ax.artists[2]

# Change the appearance of that box
mybox.set_facecolor('red')
mybox.set_edgecolor('black')
mybox.set_linewidth(3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how would you change the whiskers and mean color?
mybox.set_whiskercolor() does not work

Comment: The whiskers, the caps and the mean lines are all stored in `ax.lines`. With some trial and error you could find which line corresponds to the mean you want to change, and then do `ax.lines[X].set_color('blue')` or similar (where X is the index of the line you want to change)

Comment: A little more detail: each box has 5 lines associated with it. So `ax.lines[0:5]` corresponds to the first box, `ax.lines[5:11]` corresponds to the second box, etc. `ax.lines[0:2]` will change the whiskers, `ax.lines[2:4]` will change the caps, and `ax.lines[4]` will change the mean line for the first box

Comment: great this worked fantastically

Answer (score 6):

Seaborn uses Matplotlib under the hood. [In matplotlib 3.5 the boxes are stored in `boxes` instead of `artists`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71461460/7052826).

As such, you can set the color of boxes like so:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
                 data=tips, palette="Set3")

# Select which box you want to change    
mybox = ax.patches[2] # `patches` instead of `artists`

# Change the appearance of that box
mybox.set_facecolor('red')
mybox.set_edgecolor('black')
mybox.set_linewidth(3)
```