# Chosing individual bar colours for seasborn factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, color-palette

i was just wondering if anyone knows how to choose individual bar colours for a seaborn factor plot. I'm currently passing a list called **custom_palette** of all the colours that i want
but this just results in all the bars being the same colour.

```
plot = sns.factorplot(legend = False, x='Region', y='Values', hue='Types', data=data, kind='bar', size=8, aspect=2, palette= custom_palette)
```

[image]

Comment: what is `custom_palette`? hardcode its value into your question and use one of seaborn's bundled datasets as your data

Comment: Its just a list of different colours.

Comment: What is meant here is that you should provide a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. a code that people can copy and paste to reproduce the problem. By just looking at the plot it is not clear how the data looks like and whether this should hence work or not.

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305695/assign-a-color-to-a-specific-box-in-seaborn-boxplot/36331317#36331317