# Stylizing only some boxes with boxplots in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How would you go about changing the style of only some boxes in a matplotlib boxplot? Below, you can see an example of styling, but I would like the style to only apply to one of the boxes.

[image: Example boxplots]

Comment: What do you mean by "One of the boxes in boxplot"?

Comment: @HarvIpan In each subplot, you can see four "boxes" (consisting of a rectangle, fliers, etc.) labeled 1 through 4. I would like to apply a particular style to only one of them (e.g. by making only one box dotted). Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question has been [asked for seaborn boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305695/assign-a-color-to-a-specific-box-in-seaborn-boxplot) already. For matplotlib boxplots this is even easier, since the `boxplot` directly returns a dictionary of the involved artists, see [`boxplot` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html?highlight=boxplot#matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot).

This means that if `bplot = ax.boxplot(..)` is your boxplot, you may access the boxes via `bplot['boxes']`, select one of them and set its linestyle to your desire. E.g.

```
bplot['boxes'][2].set_linestyle("-.")
```

Modifying the [boxplot_color example](http://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot_color.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random test data
np.random.seed(19680801)
all_data = [np.random.normal(0, std, size=100) for std in range(1, 4)]
labels = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# notch shape box plot
bplot = ax.boxplot(all_data, vert=True,  patch_artist=True, labels=labels)

# Loop through boxes and colorize them individually
colors = ['pink', 'lightblue', 'lightgreen']
for patch, color in zip(bplot['boxes'], colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)

# Make the third box dotted
bplot['boxes'][2].set_linestyle("-.")
plt.show()
```

[image]