# How to color each boxplot differently

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I am trying to make a Seaborn box plot in VSCode. I am basing my code off this example here: [here](https://github.com/bvalgard/Boxplots/blob/master/Boxplots.ipynb). I am specifically making something like the penultimate example, but without the annotation.

**Code**:

```
# 0. Import the modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns


# 1. Import the data
random_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'0': np.random.rand(10),
                                 '1': np.random.rand(10),
                                 '2': np.random.rand(10),
                                 '3': np.random.rand(10),
                                 '4': np.random.rand(10)})

# 2. Do the plotting

# set style - When adding multple boxplots I like use whitegird 
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
g = sns.boxplot(data = random_df, width = 0.7)              

# with a descriptive title a ylabel might not be necessary
plt.ylabel("Accuracy", fontsize = 14)

# X tick-labels
# we are including this because I want the full product name not the variable name
xvalues = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"] 

# set xvalues as xtick values
plt.xticks(np.arange(5), xvalues)

# remove all borders except bottom
sns.despine(top=False,
            right=True,
            left=True,
            bottom=False)

# Set colors of box plots 
palette= ['plum','g','orange','b','r']
color_dict = dict(zip(xvalues, palette))

for i in range(0,5):
    mybox = g.artists[i]
    mybox.set_facecolor(color_dict[xvalues[i]])  

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**Problem:**

When I run the code in VSCode, I am getting the following error: 'index out of range'. This is pertaining to the line `g.artists[i]`; when I take that `for` loop out of my code, then the box plot can work. Also, this code only yields an error when I am using it in VSCode. When I run the code in Google Colab, then there is no error.

Comment: @JohanC - I think I am using updated versions; I just checked and my Matplotlib is v 3.5.1 and my seaborn is v 0.11.2 (from a quick google search, I think those are the newer versions)

Comment: (The recommended way to change the colors in Seaborn is to convert the dataframe to long form via `random_df.melt()` and then use `hue='variable'` and `palette=...`)

Comment: @JohanC - could you point to some examples of where I can learn more about the method where I use `df.melt()`, etc.?

Comment: [Data structures accepted by seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#data-structures-accepted-by-seaborn)

Answer (score 2):

In matplotlib 3.5 the boxes are stored in `ax.patches` instead of `ax.artists`.

The recommended way to change the colors in Seaborn is to convert the dataframe to [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) via pandas' [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) and then use `hue=` on the same variable as `x=` together with `palette=`. (`palette` can be,  among others, a dictionary or a list of colors.)

By changing the column names temporarily, the x tick labels will be set automatically. If the `ax` has been created beforehand, passing it as a parameter tells seaborn to plot onto that ax.  ([Axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) functions return the `ax` onto which the plot was created; when the `ax` is given as parameter, there is no need to store the return value.)

Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

random_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'0': np.random.rand(10),
                               '1': np.random.rand(10),
                               '2': np.random.rand(10),
                               '3': np.random.rand(10),
                               '4': np.random.rand(10)})
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 9))
xvalues = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"]
palette = ['plum', 'g', 'orange', 'b', 'r']

melted_df = random_df.set_axis(xvalues, axis=1).melt(var_name='Variable', value_name='Accuracy')
sns.boxplot(data=melted_df, x='Variable', y='Accuracy', hue='Variable', palette=palette,
            width=0.7, dodge=False, ax=ax)

ax.legend_.remove()  # remove the legend, as the information is already present in the x labels
ax.set_xlabel('')  # remove unuseful xlabel ('Variable')
ax.set_ylabel("Accuracy", fontsize=14)

sns.despine(top=True, right=True, left=True, bottom=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.boxplot on long form dataframe]

Comment: How do you change the line color? I tried a number of different approaches with the 
`for i,artist in enumerate(ax2.artists):
    # Set the linecolor on the artist to the facecolor, and set the facecolor to None
    col = artist.get_facecolor()
    artist.set_edgecolor(col)
    artist.set_facecolor('None')`
and none of them worked...

Comment: @Justyna Your code seems to update the colors of the box, not the median, nor the whiskers nor the fliers.  Maybe you can create a new question, as it is something different?

Comment: This code is an excerpt from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874697/how-to-edit-properties-of-whiskers-fliers-caps-etc-in-seaborn-boxplot/36893152#36893152 showing how to change colors of boxplot lines -- I tried to to run a copy-pasted version of it and it seems to not work in seaborn 0.11.2. I'll post a new question about it.

Comment: I added a new answer to the linked post. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874697/how-to-edit-properties-of-whiskers-fliers-caps-etc-in-seaborn-boxplot/72333641#72333641)